# How to schedule apex to run a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have a javascript function within a Visualforce page (found [here](https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/how-can-we-call-the-javascript-function-from-the-salesforce-apex-class/amp/)) that I'd like to be executed on the Salesforce platform utilizing an Apex class and the Scheduable Interface

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page controller="calljavascript_cls" >

<script>

function func()

{

alert('function calling');

}

</script>

<apex:outputText value="{!callfunc}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText value="{JavaScript}" ></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public class calljavascript_cls

{

public string callfunc{get;set;}

public calljavascript_cls()

{callfunc='<script> func(); </script>';}

}
```

I've also tried to create the scheduler class, which generates an error

```
global class scheduledMerge implements Schedulable {
   global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      calljavascript_cls();
   }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void calljavascript_cls() from the type scheduledMerge at line 3 column 7
```

I've tried to utilize the Apex Scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute javascript from apex, Visualforce (and the javascript included in it) is used to render HTML as a result of a page request from your browser.

In your example, calling the javascript function `alert('function calling')` from a Schedulable class doesn't mean anything, since Schedulable classes are executed asynchronously outside of a browser context.

What are you trying to do in your javascript function? Your best option would be to replicate that in apex. Also, that apex code could be reused from a Visualforce page if needed.

Comment: The javascript function pulls data from an external rest API, transforms it, and uploads it to Salesforce. I wanted to see if Apex can call Javascript since that'd be preferable over rebuilding the javascript in apex.